# How to convert string to list while loading from json

Tags: python, json

Json is below. I need to convert to list after loading from the json. I am getting as str

```
{
  "1": {
    "Data (L)": "[  { \"S\" : \"168\" }]"
  },
  "2": {
    "Data (L)": "[  { \"S\" : \"169\" }]"
  }
}
```

Code

```
with open('a.json') as f:
    a = json.loads(f.read())
print (a)
data1 = []
for i,j in a.items():
    data = {}
    data['id'] = i
    data1.append(data)
    for k,l in j.items():
        data[k] = l
        print (type(l))
        print (l)
```

My type pf l is `<class 'str'>` where output of `l` is `[  { "S" : "168" }]`

Expected out

print type(l) has to be list not str

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: Okay, but *why* does your json contain these weird strings, instead of the structured data that you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming, you have double-encoded json. Just call another `json.loads()` on values of second dictionaries:

```
import json

json_text = r'''{
  "1": {
    "Data (L)": "[  { \"S\" : \"168\" }]"
  },
  "2": {
    "Data (L)": "[  { \"S\" : \"169\" }]"
  }
}'''

data = json.loads(json_text)

for k, v in data.items():
    for kk, vv in v.items():
        vv = json.loads(vv)
        print(type(vv))
        print(vv)
```

Prints:

```
<class 'list'>
[{'S': '168'}]
<class 'list'>
[{'S': '169'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

## It is not a recommend method!

It is ***not secure*** to use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function this way. See [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). (Thanks to [@KarlKnechtel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/523612/karl-knechtel)
 for [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213055/how-to-convert-string-to-list-while-loading-from-json/63213172?noredirect=1#comment111780024_63213172)!)

Instead [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) can be used. See [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval). (Thanks to [@Sushanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4985099/sushanth) for [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213055/how-to-convert-string-to-list-while-loading-from-json/63213172?noredirect=1#comment111780413_63213172)!)

---

**Initial answer below**

You can use the built-in [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function like the following:

```py
s = "[  { \"S\" : \"168\" }]"
t = eval(s)

print(t)
print(type(t))
print(t[0])
print(type(t[0]))
```

which prints

```
[{'S': '168'}]
<class 'list'>
{'S': '168'}
<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Please do not ever recommend `eval` for this purpose. It is not secure.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for your comment! I'm not proud to say it, but I didn't know that.

Comment: Instead better choice would be [`ast.literal_eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/4985099)